# CRM 2016 AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm currently trying to implement the new CRM's Autocomplete in a CRM online 2016 environment.

I've used the code from [Sample: Auto-complete in CRM controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607648.aspx) and have verified that it works on the Account form and another custom entity that already exists.  However, when I use it one 1 specific custom entity and any of its string fields, the autocomplete box does not appear.

Attempts:

- Creating a new form
- Creating a brand new text field for the autocomplete to run on
- Validated that it's hitting `ext.getEventSource().showAutoComplete(resultSet);`
- Validated that no errors are being thrown from my JS

Anyone have any ideas of what might possibly be wrong?  I'm thinking it has something to do with my entity or the entity form instead of the code or the text field.

```
 /** Sample JavaScript code to demonstrate the auto-completion feature.
This sample configures the auto-complete feature for the "Account Name"
field in the account form. */

function suggestAccounts() {
    // List of sample account names to suggest
    accounts = [
      { name: 'A. Datum Corporation', code: 'A01' },
      { name: 'Adventure Works Cycles', code: 'A02' },
      { name: 'Alpine Ski House', code: 'A03' },
      { name: 'Bellows College', code: 'A04' },
      { name: 'Best For You Organics Company', code: 'A05' },
      { name: 'Blue Yonder Airlines', code: 'A06' },
      { name: 'City Power & Light', code: 'A07' },
      { name: 'Coho Vineyard', code: 'A08' },
      { name: 'Coho Winery', code: 'A09' },
      { name: 'Coho Vineyard & Winery', code: 'A10' },
      { name: 'Contoso, Ltd.', code: 'A11' },
      { name: 'Contoso Pharmaceuticals', code: 'A12' },
      { name: 'Contoso Suites', code: 'A13' },
      { name: 'Consolidated Messenger', code: 'A14' },
      { name: '​Fabrikam, Inc.', code: 'A15' },
      { name: 'Fabrikam Residences', code: 'A16' },
      { name: '​First Up Consultants', code: 'A17' },
      { name: 'Fourth Coffee', code: 'A18' },
      { name: 'Graphic Design Institute', code: 'A19' },
      { name: 'Humongous Insurance', code: 'A20' },
      { name: 'Lamna Healthcare Company', code: 'A21' },
      { name: 'Litware, Inc.', code: 'A22' },
      { name: 'Liberty Delightful Sinful Bakery & Cafe', code: 'A23' },
      { name: 'Lucerne Publishing', code: 'A24' },
      { name: 'Margie Travel', code: 'A25' },
      { name: '​Munson Pickles and Preserves Farm', code: 'A26' },
      { name: 'Nod Publishers', code: 'A27' },
      { name: 'Northwind Electric Cars', code: 'A28' },
      { name: 'Northwind Traders', code: 'A29' },
      { name: 'Proseware, Inc.', code: 'A30' },
      { name: 'Relecloud', code: 'A31' },
      { name: 'School of Fine Art', code: 'A32' },
      { name: 'Southridge Video', code: 'A33' },
      { name: 'Tailspin Toys', code: 'A34' },
      { name: 'Trey Research', code: 'A35' },
      { name: 'The Phone Company', code: 'A36' },
      { name: 'VanArsdel, Ltd.', code: 'A37' },
      { name: 'Wide World Importers', code: 'A38' },
      { name: '​Wingtip Toys', code: 'A39' },
      { name: 'Woodgrove Bank', code: 'A40' }    
    ];

    var keyPressFcn = function (ext) {
        try {
            var userInput = Xrm.Page.getControl("name").getValue();
            resultSet = {
                results: new Array(),
                commands: {
                    id: "sp_commands",
                    label: "Learn More",
                    action: function () {
                        // Specify what you want to do when the user
                        // clicks the "Learn More" link at the bottom
                        // of the auto-completion list.
                        // For this sample, we are just opening a page
                        // that provides information on working with
                        // accounts in CRM.
                        window.open("http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/create-or-edit-an-account.aspx");
                    }
                }
            };

            var userInputLowerCase = userInput.toLowerCase();
            for (i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
                if (userInputLowerCase === accounts[i].name.substring(0, userInputLowerCase.length).toLowerCase()) {
                    resultSet.results.push({
                        id: i,
                        fields: [accounts[i].name]
                    });
                }
                if (resultSet.results.length >= 10) break;
            }

            if (resultSet.results.length > 0) {
                ext.getEventSource().showAutoComplete(resultSet);
            } else {
                ext.getEventSource().hideAutoComplete();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // Handle any exceptions. In the sample code,
            // we are just displaying the exception, if any.
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    Xrm.Page.getControl("name").addOnKeyPress(keyPressFcn);    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a lookup control on the form in order for the autocomplete to render. It sounds weird but this is currently the best workaround. I set mine to not be visible. Note: this is any lookup field it does not matter the relationship you choose. Having the lookup field sets something on the form to load the missing libraries.

I spend most of my weekend trying to figure out a similar situation. I could describe at great lengths the events that led to this discovery, but I will spare you.

I assume that Microsoft is trying to not include resources where they do not see a configured need and that is why the back-end autocomplete files are missing (until you add in a requirement for them).

Comment: That's weird but it's true. Worked on my environment too.

Comment: Actually there is a message "Error on page" on status bar and if you run Jscript debugger in Visual Studio you'll see the error in output window.
Says "0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: I can't believe...even in in the latest CRM Online version this is still an issue.  Just tried it, this is correct